# how to display external application in layout without iframe

Tags: visualforce, canvas, iframe

Hi I was wondering what the best way to display an external application in Salesforce (Lead Layout, Contact Layout, etc) without using an iframe. I am asking because the new package has the "Enable clickjacking prevention" feature which breaks the app. I have tried both visualforce pages and canvas apps but they both seem to still be using iframes....

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you